# Why are my divs not handling overflow properly when using overflow-y scroll?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have a sidebar and content area that are two columns, I want them to have responsive height to fill the screen rather than a fixed height as I don't know an exact size (i.e. if a page banner shows up, the layout should respond appropriately).

I've tried setting overflow-y scroll on the tab-content container and tab-panes individually, as well as heights and max heights, but no matter what I do if a tab-pane holds too many items it will spill out and cause the whole page to scroll, rather than add a scrollbar only to the tab pane.

I've created an example in JS Fiddle. You can see that in the overview section with very few inputs there is no scrollbar, but in a large section like section 4, a page scrollbar is added because the overflow is not contained. This leads to the sidebar being scrolled as well and is generally a mess.

I'm looking for a way to contain the content to the maximum space available on the screen, but I cannot use px or view-height values, as it needs to be responsive. For example, any fix should not push content off the screen when the alert div is uncommented.

https://jsfiddle.net/ezcnfLvg/22/

[image: No scrolling, all content contained on page]

[image: When too many items, content is pushed off the page and not properly contained]

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>

  <style>
    body {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .sidebar {
    max-width: 18rem;
  }

  .tab-content {
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
    max-height: 99%;
    height: 99%;
  }

  .tab-pane {
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
    /* max-height: 99%; */
    /* height: 99%; */
  }
  </style>

  <!-- <div class="alert alert-primary my-0" role="alert">
    Uncomment me to see if I break the formatting!
  </div> -->
  
  <div class="container-fluid flex-grow-1 row">
    <nav class="col-auto sidebar px-2 bg-dark">
    <ul class="nav flex-column nav-pills mx-3" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link  active" id="sidebar_overview" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#section_overview" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="section_overview" aria-selected="true">
                Overview
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link " id="sidebar_section2" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#section2" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="section2" aria-selected="false">
                Section2
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link " id="sidebar_section3" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#section3" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="section3" aria-selected="false">
              Section3
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link " id="sidebar_section4" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#section4" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="section4" aria-selected="false">
            Section4
            </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  
    <form action="" class="col tab-content">
      <fieldset class="tab-pane fade show col ms-5 mt-4 active" id="section_overview" role="tabpanel">
          <legend>Overview</legend>
          <hr>
  
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
      </fieldset>
  
      <fieldset class="tab-pane fade col ms-5 mt-4" id="section2" role="tabpanel">
          <legend>Section 2</legend>
          <hr>
  
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </fieldset>
  
      <fieldset class="tab-pane fade col ms-5 mt-4" id="section3" role="tabpanel">
          <legend>Section 3</legend>
          <hr>
  
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </fieldset>
  
      <fieldset class="tab-pane fade col ms-5 mt-4" id="section4" role="tabpanel">
          <legend>Section 4</legend>
          <hr>
  
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">

          <legend>Subsection 4</legend>
          <hr>

          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">

          <br>


          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">
          <label for="">Some Value</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control">

          <br>
          <span class="fs-4">The End of Section 4</span>
      </fieldset>
  
    </form>
  </div>
  
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using % to set the height of the div.

Make the following adjustments:

1. To the body add `overflow-y:hidden;`
2. To the `.tab-content` change `height` and `max-height` to `99vh` instead of `99%`.

Working example:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.sidebar {
  max-width: 18rem;
}

.tab-content {
  overflow-y: scroll !important;
  max-height: 99vh;
  height: 99vh;
}

.tab-pane {
  overflow-y: scroll !important;
  /* max-height: 99%; */
  /* height: 99%; */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
  <!-- <div class="alert alert-primary my-0" role="alert">
    Uncomment me to see if I break the formatting!
  </div> -->

  <div class="container-fluid flex-grow-1 row">
    <nav class="col-auto sidebar px-2 bg-dark">
      <ul class="nav flex-column nav-pills mx-3" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link  active" id="sidebar_overview" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#section_overview" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="section_overview" aria-selected="true">
                Overview
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link " id="sidebar_section2" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#section2" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="section2" aria-selected="false">
                Section2
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link " id="sidebar_section3" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#section3" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="section3" aria-selected="false">
              Section3
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link " id="sidebar_section4" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#section4" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="section4" aria-selected="false">
            Section4
            </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <form action="" class="col tab-content">
      <fieldset class="tab-pane fade show col ms-5 mt-4 active" id="section_overview" role="tabpanel">
        <legend>Overview</legend>
        <hr>

        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <label for="">Some Value</label>
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset class="tab-pane fade col ms-5 mt-4" id="section2" role="tabpanel">
        <legend>Section 2</legend>
        <hr>

        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset class="tab-pane fade col ms-5 mt-4" id="section3" role="tabpanel">
        <legend>Section 3</legend>
        <hr>

        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset class="tab-pane fade col ms-5 mt-4" id="section4" role="tabpanel">
        <legend>Section 4</legend>
        <hr>

        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">

        <legend>Subsection 4</legend>
        <hr>

        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">

        <br>


        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
        <label for="">Some Value</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">

        <br>
        <span class="fs-4">The End of Section 4</span>
      </fieldset>

    </form>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! I had tried the vh units but it seems like this missing piece was the overflow-y: hidden on body, could you explain to me why that is necessary? As I understand it, having the tab-pane manage its own content overflow with scroll should be enough so I'm not understanding why body would need to be modified

Comment: @Seltonu When specifying overflow for child elements but not for their parent, the parent will try to accommodate all its content. In your case, the child elements are designed to handle their own overflow, but without a corresponding overflow rule on the body, the body would also attempt to fit all the content it encloses. As a result, the body and the child are trying to manage the same content, causing a conflict. By setting overflow-y: hidden; on the body, you're effectively telling the body that it should rely on its children to handle their own overflow.